# log4j doesn't write in log file on tomcat7 (ubuntu server)

Tags: java, web, log4j, tomcat7, ubuntu-16.04

This is my log4j.properties file:

```
# LOG4J configuration
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, Appender1,Appender2
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info
log4j.logger.org.quartz=info

log4j.appender.Appender1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n

log4j.appender.Appender2=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.Appender2.File=/home/diego/proyect/log/general.log
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n
```

Locally works on my windows machine, but on the server (ubuntu 16.04) side the web application cannot write on the .log file, already modified permissions for the file:

```
chmod 777 /home/diego/proyect/log/general.log
```

this is the resuls of **ls -lhs** on the log directory:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 diego diego 0 Nov 16 14:23 general.log
```

Also not sure which is the tomcat user on the server.

Comment: The line `#log4j...=/.../general.log` is comment in your config file.

Comment: Sorry my bad, isn't commented on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved, it seems I need to add the log4j.properties files into the classpath, my project has the following structure:

- main

  - src/main/java
  - **src/main/resources/log4j.properties**
  - webapp

    - WEB-INF/log4j.properties

So I put the file under **src/main/resources** directory and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it is working  on local environment mean that your configuration is correct. I think there is an issue with your environment. Here are a few things to check:

Does the tomcat process has permissions to write in file . i.e. are administrator rights required to write?

Check that there aren't any temporary files near tomcat's directories which may be preventing your changes.

Check that you don't have any other log4j config files on your classpath, as these could override your log4j file and preventing it . To double check this, you could try temporarily removing your log4j.properties file .